# how to create a flex project with workers?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I'm trying to convert my app to use workers.

I've extended some classes to be sprites.. then I added them as workers at projects panel.
But the following error comes when I try to use a tutorial:

> 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Worker.

I'm using flash builder 4.7 beta, Apache Flex SDK 4.8 installed by "installapacheflex" application, and AIR 3.4

Comment: You're going to have upgrade the Flash Player / Adobe AIR SDKs for the project; as the Worker APIs are new.  I haven't been watching closely, so I'm unclear if workers are available publicly or in a formal release yet.  You may have to get the relevant SDK updates from Adobe Labs.  You probably shouldn't have to recompile Flex from the source, though.

Comment: This link: http://www.bytearray.org/?p=4516 has some information about the workers api as does this one: http://www.bytearray.org/?p=4423  Not sure if these will help, but perhaps they will.

Comment: BTW, you should check out [AS3-Worker-Compat](https://github.com/jcward/AS3-Worker-Compat) - it can be compiled by any SDK, creates SWFs that will work in any version of the player, and optionally use Workers if they are available.

Answer (score 0):

For now Workers support only for action-script projects which is using AIR SDK 3.5, still not sure how to use workers in flex SDK 4.6.

[Check this link](http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=162) for more information

Comment: yes, I see now that the Flash Builder workers API or IDE or whatever is not yet public. Thanks